# No response from remote host for Nagios check_snmp_mem.pl plugin

Tags: monitoring, nagios, snmp

Trying to setup memory usage monitoring for Nagios using the `check_snmp_mem.pl` from Nagios SNMP plugin.

I could not even get it working from the command line, I mean I go to `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins` and run the script, it gets a "No response from remote host" error.

```
[root@nagios plugins]# ./check_snmp_mem.pl -H rhel01 -C public -N -w 90,20 -c 99,30
Argument "v6.0.1" isn't numeric in numeric lt (<) at ./check_snmp_mem.pl line 319.
ERROR: Description table : No response from remote host "rhel01".
```

Any SNMP configurations required on the monitored server?

Comment: Yes, you do need to have snmpd enabled and running on the remote host and configured to allow the Nagios server to contact it. Try using `snmpwalk` to test the snmp service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from another colleague, we worked out why it didn't work.

3 things:

- First, we have agentaddress tcp:x.x.x.x:161 in snmpd.conf, just deleted the line
- Second, iptables is blocking udp port 161, added rules to allow udp port 161
- Third, something wrong with the script as you can see the error message about line 319, changed `<` to `lt`